# I had or I have?

Tags: email

I would like to send email to my boss
About exam of the course she told me to take it.

Dear Mrs. Jeny,

I hope my email find you well.

I would like to inform inform you that I have passed the science test ..

Or

I would like to inform you that I had passed the science test .

Kindest regards,

Cathren

Comment: "Had" does not even make sense. Also, there are other errors in the email. That said, none of that matters one bit. It's an email, not a State of the Union address. It brings the point across, and that's all that matters. Just send it off already and call it a day.

Comment: You have to use **"had"** when talking about some time in the past and some event had occurred even before that time. Eg "My mother screamed at me, thinking that I had failed the exam, but I had passed with ease". Sequence of events : "pass exam" & "mother screams" & "now". If you have only two events "pass exam" & "now", then use **"have"**. So "I would like to inform you that I **have** passed the science test."